# Can I re-enter Brazil on a tourist visa after student visa expires?

Tags: visas, brazil, uk-citizens

I am a student from the UK, and I will be finishing my semester here in Rio de Janeiro in mid June. My student visa expires on 3rd August, however I intend to leave the country on 17th July in order to go travelling around South America for a month.

My problem is that I want to re-enter the country on 18th August in order to collect some luggage which I don't want to take with me on my travels. My return flight to London is 20th August. I am just wondering if I will be able to re-enter the country on a tourist visa, just for a night or two, considering my student visa will have expired by this point?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should get confirmation from immigration, but I'm quite sure that whether you had a student visa for Brazil does not affect your obtaining a tourist visa afterwards.

As a British citizen you can obtain a visa/stamp at the border. Upon entry, you might be asked to show proof of future departure.

My point above is related to the fact that on a tourist visa, you're only allowed to stay in Brazil for a total of 180 days within a 12 month period. But, as said, I don't think that having stayed in Brazil on a student visa adds up to that.

Here's a host of info on visas for Brazil:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Brazil